# Is foliation the right word?

Tags: terminology, curves

Let say $C$ is a Jordan curve (rectifiable, closed with not self-intersections). Is there a term for the family $\{tC\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$? Is "foliation" the right word?

Comment: That is not the right word, no. Is there a reason you want a word for that family? On the other hand, I don't know why this question was downvoted.

Comment: What's wrong with "family of Jordan curves"? @MikeMiller I could see people in the qc/dynamical systems area refer to that as a foliation, even though I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi your question is kind of philosophical. An honest answer is that Im giving a talk soon and have to use "family of Jordan curves" multiple times. I don't like to say that long phrase 20 times.

Comment: Call it a Jordan family, or just a family or something, then. If notation doesn't exist, make up your own.

Comment: Well, then if your audience is made of geometers, do not use "foliation". With us analysts, you might. I have seen many geometry terms repurposed for similar uses.

Comment: ill keep it kosher and won't use then. you never know who's sitting in your audience.last thing I want is to tick someone off.

Comment: @MikeMiller Using the word "foliation" in a context where no manifolds or tangent bundles appear, it is exactly making up his own notation. I think it's acceptable, possibly not optimal.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: Eh, I would object because it doesn't really help us understand what's going on, even if it doesn't conflict with terminology the audience has heard before. I think the word 'foliation' provides a rich geometric picture... after you've been immersed in it for a while, but not instantaneously. I would rather call it a family of Jordan curves. :)

Comment: @MikeMiller What I am imagining is a sort of level sets situation, which, yes, I can agree, it's not as rich of a picture as what a foliation is, but it's still something. But again, the first words I have spoken here are "What's wrong with "family of Jordan curves"?" so I guess we (half-)agree. ;) (I assume you had less contact than me with dynamics people, I probably got too used to their use of terminology)

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: Unfortunately it's true that I do not have much contact with dynamicists. Geometers do use the term "singular foliation", which is almost precisely what it sounds like you're saying - eg cutting $S^2$ into its longitudinal spheres and the north and south poles is a singular foliation, and can be given as a partition into level sets of a function. In any case this is pretty tangential to the question, so maybe we should take it to email; mine is in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the use of the term "foliation" is not advisable in such a context, as foliation has a different mathematical meaning.

That being said, it is sometimes acceptable to borrow terms from another area of mathematics, as long as there's no chance of confusion. Even in that case, clarifying your terminology is always a good idea.

Comment: I learned that the most suitable term is *homothetic curves*.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the most suitable term is **homothetic curves**.